# Get data from table that linked using Foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables User and Roles

Here is Model for User

```
 public partial class User
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public User()
    {
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And here is Model for Roles

```
public partial class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Nullable<int> User_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I need to show in View Name of User and his RoleName

In Controller I have this method

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).ToList());
    }
```

And in View this

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>


    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

I try to display RoleName like

```
<td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Roles.Name)
        </td>
```

But it not see `RoleName` property.

How I can fix this?

Comment: I reopened question @mjwills

Answer (score 0):

You have a collection of roles property in the User class which means one user can have many roles. if your intention is to have many roles for one user you might have to include an another foreach loop as below

[image]

If your intention is to have one role per user probably you can use the below code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per your models each user has a set of roles.
We will need to loop the roles to be able to display the RoleName.

```
@foreach (var role in item.Roles) {
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => role.RoleName)
    </td>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In User Model you have declared Roles as a Collection it means list. From your code you have Roles list inside every User. 
If you have only one role for each user you can change you code like:

```
<td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Roles.First().RoleName)
        </td>
```

This will display the FirstRole Name from Roles list.

or you can loop the Roles like User